# Trying to get Selenium Chrome Driver to refresh page until an item is found, but all methods failing

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing a program that is supposed to refresh a website until a certain item is loaded (I am not loading the item manually but the people running the website) but my methods don't seem to work. I tried to use FluentWait along with driver.navigate().refresh() (<-- would only refresh the chromedriver browser once by the way) but learned that in this case that is not what I need. Below are my attempts. Any guidance on how I can solve this problem is appreciated!

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Washed Twill Short")));
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Washed Twill Short"));
driver.get(link.getAttribute("href"));

Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait(driver).withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

WebElement refresher = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() 
            {
                public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) 
                {
                    driver.navigate().refresh();    
                    return driver.findElement(By.linkText("Washed Twill Short"));           
                }
            });

Boolean isPresent = driver.findElements(By.linkText("Washed Twill Short")).size() > 0;
while(!isPresent)
            {
                driver.get(driver.getCurrentUrl());
            }

do{
   driver.navigate().refresh();
 }while(!driver.findElement(By.linkText("Washed Twil Short")).isDisplayed());

String productlink = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Washed Twill Short")).getAttribute("href");
driver.get(productlink);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are quite close. You can either use the `findElement()` method, but that method will throw a `NoSuchElementException` that will break the normal flow. In that case you have to surround your call with a try-catch.

A better approach (which you also tried) is to use the `findElements()` method which returns an empty list if nothing matches. But you have misplaced your stop criteria and only checking it once *before* looping. Move the check into the loop, and get something like this:

```
String url = /* some url */
driver.get(url);
while(driver.findElements(By.linkText("Washed Twill Short")).isEmpty())
{
    driver.get(url);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply and explanation  @Per Huss . Unfortunately, for some reason, the browser still only gets/reloads the page once. Your code looks correct to me, so I'm not really sure why it's still only reloading once and not until an element is found.

Comment: If that code only loads the page once, my next guess is that's because it actually finds a link with that text within the page... Try debugging and se what the findElements actually returns...

Comment: I tested it out using "Washed Twil Short" to ensure it wouldn't be found. What it does is it refreshes once and doesn't go on to the product page and later to checkout (as expected except for the one refresh). @Per Huss

Comment: But if I write driver.navigate().refresh() on its own a bunch of times, it will refresh all those times (but need it only until it finds an element). This is a strange scenario. I keep trying different methods but the only way that it's refreshing multiple times is by writing driver.navigate().refresh() a lot.

Comment: Something is fishy here... I just tried the code I posted preceded by a `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver()` and using `"http://www.google.com" as the url. It reloads the page at a high rate...

Comment: I kind of figured out what the problem was. When I used your first suggestion, it wouldn't work when I inputted a link text that wasn't in the source code (similar to inputting a link text of a product that is about to release). However, when I tested it with an already loaded item, it refreshed perfectly. I was receiving NullPointer errors because the item (my fake link text) wasn't on the page at all. So I changed the while loop to while (driver.findElement(By.linkText ("fake product") == null)) -> refresh. That also gave me a NullPointer error. The problem with all the attempts have been

Comment: That when I inputted a link text of an item not yet available, but about to be updated on the page I would receive NullPointers. Otherwise if I used loaded items the driver.navigate ().refresh () would work exactly how I want it to (using your method with loaded product link text)